# how to remove the vertical line in InteliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I open my IntelliJ IDEA which is 2021.01 version, and got a vertical line in the middle, and I want to know how to remove it?

Here is the screenshot of the vertical line which is in the red frame.

[image: the vertical line i got in InteliJ IDEA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a visual indicator showing you your line-wrapping. You can deactivate it by going to **Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Appearance**  and unticking `Show hard wrap and visual guides`

[image: appearance settings IntelliJ IDEA]